# How to embed JSON Google map to website?

Tags: json, google-maps

A client of mine sent me a JSON file. It's supposed to display a google map location once embedded on the site. But I am not sure how to embed this into the site. Here's a sample of what it looks like:

```
[
{
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#ec0000"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#008006"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "landscape.natural",
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks,

K

Comment: Ask him.  Look at the documentation for the [Google Maps Javascript API Styled Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) or [Google Maps Javascript API v3 DataLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That JSON file will not display a map. If you wanted to display a map based on data from a JSON file, you would write Maps API code to interpret the JSON data and display the map, or use a GeoJSON layer. But that particular JSON file doesn't have information like geographic coordinates or anything like that. The file isn't GeoJSON (JSON with geographic information). Instead, it contains settings that are used to *style* a map, as described here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling#style_syntax

In other words, this data could be used to control the appearance of a map, but not the actual contents of the map.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!